# Windows 10 NotifyIcon Icon always looks very pixilated

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, icons

I am having trouble making a NotifyIcon in Windows 10 whose icon resource looks anything but a blurry mess.

[image: Icon]

This happens with both icons from the `SystemIcons` class, or my own using `Properties.Resources`. I have tried creating a new instance of the icon with the `Icon (Icon original, int width, int height)` constructor, and all sorts of other mad things, including this nugget:

```
Icon ico = Icon.FromHandle((new Icon(Resources.InfoIcon, 256, 256).ToBitmap()).GetHicon());
```

to no avail. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to display the resources with their original dimensions?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you mean, but the .ico file I have there contains 9 icons, from 256x256 right down to 16x16, and I have tried all the sizes manually to no avail.

Comment: @HansPassant, In fact, that was the first method I used to try and display a `NotifyIcon`. It does not display anything... unless you give it an icon parameter, which it promptly ignores. (A fact I literally just now discovered). This would also mean I cannot use custom icons. As for that linked post, it did not work for me; maybe something to do with VS 2015?

Comment: It sure looks like trash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The poor icon in the screenshot is easy to address, you forgot to set the [NotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.balloontipicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Or use the NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip() method overload that takes ToolTipIcon.  With `ToolTipIcon.Info` you'll get the high resolution system default icon.  For example:

```
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "eDIDIO", 
        "Connected successfully!", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

Which produces:

[image]

If you want your own icon to show up in this notification "balloon" then you have to work around a restriction in the ResourceManager.GetObject() method.  Which is what you are using when you write "Resources.InfoIcon".  GetObject() does not have enough arguments to be selective about the icon size you prefer.  Use the code shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4027068/17034).  Never use GetHicon() btw, it does a very poor job at color palette mapping and can only produce a 16 color icon.

Comment: Thanks, I can now get nice icons if I want to use default ones (which honestly, I probably will). The answer you linked to does not give me any resources though. Additionally, why is it that i have to set the `NotifyIcon.Icon` property _as well as_ the `NotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon` property to get the `BalloonTipIcon` to show?

Comment: The Icon and BalloonTipIcon are very different properties.  BalloonTipIcon is not an Icon type property, it is an enum.

Comment: Hans, I would like to use ToolTipIcon.None and have it pull my own Icon, but what size do I need to use to make it look nice? Will it share a 64x64 icon?

Comment: actually, it looks like that icon is 20

Comment: Hans, I've been working on this for a bit, and it seems setting the NotifyIcon.Icon to different size icons doesn't make a difference - is it pulling the icon from somewhere else?