# c# Balloon Tip Text: Remove Project text from notification

Tags: c#, notifications

I am using Balloon tip text in C# and everything is working as expected.  However whenever my notifications appear, there will be subtext that correlates to the project name.

How do I remove this text?

Notification image:

[image]

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon(SystemIcons.Application, 40, 40);
notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
notifyIcon1.Text = "Application Installation";
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "The App installaion has started.";
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Test App Installation";
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey so i think i have a start for you atleast. As you can see in the image below i managed to remove the name of the exectuable file that it was running from.

[image: Example]

I found a example here [how to show Balloon tip like Windows 10 Balloon tip without stretching icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760898/how-to-show-balloon-tip-like-windows-10-balloon-tip-without-stretching-icon) and the example from **cokeman19** where you can add your own custom icon. Although this does not seem to work when you dont want the exectuable name at the bottom.

If you want to do some changes i recommend you to look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352(v=vs.85).aspx since it provied some nice hints on what to do.
Here is the code that i made a few changes too so we get what we want.

```
    public class NotifyIconLarge : IDisposable
    {
        [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int Shell_NotifyIcon(int message, NOTIFYICONDATA pnid);

        [DllImport("Comctl32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadIconWithScaleDown(IntPtr hinst, string pszName, int cx, int cy, out IntPtr phico);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);

        private const int NIF_LARGE_ICON = 0x00000040;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public class NOTIFYICONDATA
        {
            public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));
            public IntPtr hWnd;
            public int uID;
            public int uFlags;
            public int uCallbackMessage;
            public IntPtr hIcon;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
            public string szTip;
            public int dwState;
            public int dwStateMask;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
            public string szInfo;
            public int uTimeoutOrVersion;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string szInfoTitle;
            public int dwInfoFlags;
            Guid guidItem;
            public IntPtr hBalloonIcon;
        }

        private IntPtr _windowHandle;
        private IntPtr _hIcon;
        private bool _added;
        private int _id = 1;
        private string _tipText;

        public NotifyIconLarge(IntPtr windowHandle, string tipText)
        {
            _windowHandle = windowHandle;
            _tipText = tipText;
            IntPtr result = LoadIconWithScaleDown(IntPtr.Zero, "", 0, 0, out _hIcon);
            UpdateIcon(true);
        }

        private void UpdateIcon(bool showIconInTray)
        {
            NOTIFYICONDATA nOTIFYICONDATA = new NOTIFYICONDATA();
            nOTIFYICONDATA.uCallbackMessage = 2048;
            nOTIFYICONDATA.uFlags = 1;
            nOTIFYICONDATA.hWnd = _windowHandle;
            nOTIFYICONDATA.uID = _id;
            nOTIFYICONDATA.hIcon = IntPtr.Zero;
            nOTIFYICONDATA.szTip = null;
            if (_hIcon != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                nOTIFYICONDATA.uFlags |= 1;
                nOTIFYICONDATA.hIcon = _hIcon;
            }
            nOTIFYICONDATA.uFlags |= 4;
            nOTIFYICONDATA.szTip = _tipText;
            nOTIFYICONDATA.hBalloonIcon = _hIcon;
            if (showIconInTray)
            {
                if (!_added)
                {
                    Shell_NotifyIcon(0, nOTIFYICONDATA);
                    _added = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Shell_NotifyIcon(1, nOTIFYICONDATA);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (_added)
                {
                    Shell_NotifyIcon(2, nOTIFYICONDATA);
                    _added = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public void ShowBalloonTip(int timeout, string tipTitle, string tipText, ToolTipIcon tipIcon)
        {
            NOTIFYICONDATA nOTIFYICONDATA = new NOTIFYICONDATA();
            nOTIFYICONDATA.hWnd = _windowHandle;
            nOTIFYICONDATA.uID = _id;
            nOTIFYICONDATA.uFlags = 16;
            nOTIFYICONDATA.uTimeoutOrVersion = timeout;
            nOTIFYICONDATA.szInfoTitle = tipTitle;
            nOTIFYICONDATA.szInfo = tipText;
            switch (tipIcon)
            {
                case ToolTipIcon.None:
                    nOTIFYICONDATA.dwInfoFlags = NIF_LARGE_ICON;
                    break;
                case ToolTipIcon.Info:
                    nOTIFYICONDATA.dwInfoFlags = 1;
                    break;
                case ToolTipIcon.Warning:
                    nOTIFYICONDATA.dwInfoFlags = 2;
                    break;
                case ToolTipIcon.Error:
                    nOTIFYICONDATA.dwInfoFlags = 3;
                    break;
            }
            int ret = Shell_NotifyIcon(1, nOTIFYICONDATA);
        }

        public void RemoveFromTray()
        {
            UpdateIcon(false);
            if (_hIcon != IntPtr.Zero)
                DestroyIcon(_hIcon);
        }

        ~NotifyIconLarge()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            RemoveFromTray();
        }
    }
```

So first you declare the NotifyIconLarge class somewhere.

```
      private NotifyIconLarge _nil;
```

Then to create a notify popup you use the following code:

```
    _nil = new NotifyIconLarge(Handle, "Icon Tip");
    _nil.ShowBalloonTip(10000, "Balloon Title", "Balloon Text", ToolTipIcon.None);
```

When you are finished with the tray remove it:

```
    _nil.RemoveFromTray();
```

Credits to **cokeman19** for most of the code